# How to annotate an image in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, deep-learning, annotations, image-segmentation

I am new to react-native.  I need to create an volume estimation app from food images.  For volume estimation, I need a segmentation json file whose format is in the form of labelme annotations.

But when I use labelme I have to manually draw polygons around the image.
Can I do something similiar in react-native like when I upload an image I can draw a polygon around the image and retrieve its coordinates.  Then I could convert the coordinates into labelme annotation json file.

Any suggestions?
Thank You